# Creating a new instance from a class stored in a hashmap

Tags: java, class, hashmap

I'm stuck on a problem with creating a new instance from a stored class in an hashmap.

I'm doing : 
saving an instance of a class to a hashmap as referal to load classes from by UIN (unique item name) ((which is a string))

problem : 
the instance saved stays the same, resulting in placing the same instance for every block saved, which results in only one block being replaced when a save is loaded.

looking for : how would i create a new instance so i can place all my blocks properly back ?

Code :

Registering:

```
/*======================Registry===========================*/
public static HashMap<String, Block> registeredBlocks = new HashMap<String, Block>();

public static void registerBlock(Block block){
    registeredBlocks.put(block.getUIN(), block);
}

public static void loadBlocks(){
    registerBlock(new BlockChest());
    registerBlock(new BlockTree());

    System.out.println(registeredBlocks);
    System.out.println(registeredBlocks.containsKey("chestBlock"));
    System.out.println(registeredBlocks.get("chestBlock"));
    System.out.println(Blocks.chest);
}

public static Block getBlockFromUIN(String uin){
    if(registeredBlocks.containsKey(uin)){
        return registeredBlocks.get(uin);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Reference

```
public static BlockChest chest = (BlockChest)Block.registeredBlocks.get("chestBlock");
public static BlockTree log = (BlockTree)Block.registeredBlocks.get("treeLog");
```

Comment: Some objects support the Cloneable interface, allowing you to conveniently copy them.  Otherwise you can use `someObject.getClass().newInstance()` to create an instance of the class if you don't need to provide any creation parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You're not storing classes in your hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, Block> registeredBlocks
```

This is mapping Strings to `Block` instances, hence the behavior you're observing.

Instead:

```
HashMap<String, Class> registeredBlocks
```

will store Class objects

```
registeredBlocks.put(block.getUIN(), block.getClass());  //or Block.class
```

will put the `Block` class to your map with whatever the key String is, and

```
Block b = (Block)registeredBlocks.get(keyString).newInstance();
```

will give you a new instance of that class, cast to `Block`.

Note 1: this is utilizing the [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) method.

Note 2: This is meant purely as an answer to your question. What you're trying to do is not immediately apparent in your post, but I'm fairly confident there's a cleaner/better way to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Try not to use raw types. (Even if it changes nothing in this example.)

Comment: This coudld do very well. I'll try this out, but I'll keep looking for a neater way too.